# ios: Make a view contained by another view rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation, addsubview

I have a little problem I can't find a way to solve. I have a view inside another view that doesn't rotate when the main view rotates... It's a bit mess up said this way, so I will write a little code:

```
//in my ViewController:
UIView insideView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
insideView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0];
...
[self.view addSubview:insideView];
```

Now, I can't realize why, if I roteate my iPhone (simulator), the **insideView** doesn't follow the main **self.view**.

Comment: Follow it in what way? What auto resizing/layout do you have?

Comment: What version of iOS are you writing to, what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I'm using xcode 5, and iOS 6.0

Comment: I never used auto resizing/layout, maybe it's this the problem. When should I set them? Please excuse me, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following approach

```
[self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

The setAutoresizesSubviews property controls whether each view will resize automatically when their bounds change. The setAutoresizingMask property controls how each object resizes automatically.